# MsDeploy synchronization completed in XX pass(es)

Tags: synchronization, msdeploy

What is the sequence of executing the providers list within a Manifest.
I have seen at times our builds take 5 passes to sync, while some times we get errors that the sync did not complete due to sync limit reached.
Is there a documentation around how and what gets executed within each sync phase and is there a way to influence it.

Thanks,
Yatin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The providers are executed in the order in which they appear in the manifest.

We've seen this error when we had internal network/firewall issues.  All cleared after network operations fixed the problem.

EDIT

You should also check that none of the files on the target server are marked readonly. This can cause the sync to fail and retry multiple times.  You can try deleting all the target files and deploying them fresh.

Third party tools can also cause this to happen.  Dropbox, OneDrive or a virus scanner may be editing files after they are synched then WebDeploy has to resync again.

SUMMARY

Something is changing the website files or adding files to the folder between each pass.  Based on your other question it looks like you are adding DacPacs to the website folder which is causing this.

[MsDeploy Sync not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751657/msdeploy-sync-not-working/37840098#37840098)

Comment: I agree, the providers are executed in order, but I would assume when it says 'passes' it has executed all providers at once and such xx passes.
What I do not understand is why it does not execute all paths of a provider at one shot. If there is a logic in executing providers, such as inter-dependencies then how do we understand those?
(I do not see any network issues when I see the errors in my log file.)

Comment: Multiple sync passes is a feature of WebDeploy.  It runs through all provider multiple times to verify the sync worked correctly.  I added more causes of this error in my answer.  Are you running any post deploy scripts?

Comment: We are not running any post deploy scripts.

Is there any documentation around this process? 
The server do not have any DropBox or OneDrive.
There is virus scanner, but cannot find a reason it should 'edit' any of website content files.
The files are not readonly

Comment: Run the deploy with the -verbose flag and see if it provides more information.  Built in post deploy (postsync) - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619740(v=ws.10).aspx Custom post deploy - http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/05/19/extending-the-webdeploy-manifest/

Comment: Here is link to a zip file that has logs, refer to packageDeployment.log file.
Looks to me that its taking more than 1 iteration is due to not able to update parameters in the target files.

Comment: I was able to remove multiple passes by 
1> removing obsolete parameters from declare parameter & set parameter files.
2> Carefully re-configuring parameters such that the value in SetParameter file is different than the value being replaced for the target parameter.