# MsDeploy Sync not working

Tags: synchronization, filepath, msdeploy

We have our sql project build built as `dacpac` and has dependency on `master.dacpac`, the `dacpac` is included with the website content.

Both `dacpac`'s are included in the package through `filePath` provider.
I can see the package contains the `dacpac`'s together.

On the target directory however, the `master.dacpac` is sync'ed correctly, (deleted and then added from package). But the application `dacpac` is not sync'ed (in fact, the package is added first and then deleted, effectively loosing the file from target).

All other files of website seems to be unpacking correctly.

Comment: Are both DacPacs in the same location?  I believe the package will unpack the file to a location based on the path it was packed from.

Comment: Yes, the dacpacs are in same location, they are in the package file created for deployment.
Unpacking seems to be fine, its the sync operation that is working weird.
Things were fine, not sure what would have caused sync operation to fail !!

Comment: Can you add the DacPac snippet from your archive.xml to the question above?  The archive file is inside the zipped package.

Comment: I've all log files reduced to minimum to show the issue.
Here is link to Google Drive zip file that contains log file and manifest
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwO5Oin30M6IcS0tWHowWndDQ1k/view?usp=sharing 
Here is snapshot of the dacpac
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwO5Oin30M6IbkJublhFbW5jdzQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the target path for the website?  What is the target path for the DacPacs?

Comment: Target path for the website and dacpacs is the root directory of the website, which is 'c:\inetpub\MyWebApp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments under the question above I believe your issue is you are syncing the DacPacs to the website root.  The website doesn't have those files in its file list so it attempts to remove those files on each sync pass.

Try syncing the DacPacs to a different folder that's not part of the web app path.

This should also fix your other question - [MsDeploy synchronization completed in XX pass(es)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657801/msdeploy-synchronization-completed-in-xx-passes/37658840?noredirect=1#comment63102436_37658840)

Comment: Interesting...
If you look at the log file, the msdeploy does add and delete the file. 
But the sequence is reversed.. it adds the file again and then deletes it.
I will try to synch to some other location and try.

Comment: Moreover, the master.dapac deploys each time correctly, but its application dacpac that has problem each time...

Comment: Changed the path for the dacpacs to temp folder, and the deployment seems more consistent than before. 
I will wait for a few more tries to accept the answer, looks promising.
----------------------
Also, I was able to resolve the multiple passes issues by eliminating Parameter declarations which were obsolete.
-----------------------
Parameter update message was confusing when the parameter value is same as replacement value. The message says it did not find parameter to update, instead should say nothing to update.

Comment: If this post was super helpful you can up-vote it in addition to marking it as the answer.  Glad this helped you.